# Artifactory with docker-compose not able to use postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker, artifactory

I am trying to run latest Artifactory 7 OSS with docker-compose. And I do not want to use Derby database, but postgresql.

According to the documentation, I need to define the ENV variables:

```
environment:
  - DB_TYPE=postgresql
  - DB_USER=user
  - DB_PASSWORD=mypass
  - DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql-docker:5432/database
```

That seems correct, but when launching the server, I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://postgresql-docker:5432/database
```

Seems that is still using the Derby driver and not the postgresql (that I expect by using the parameter DB_TYPE).

How can I force it to use postgresql? There is no DB_TYPE variable or similar on the documentation. Which ones are the correct parameters for Artifactory 7 OSS?

Comment: the docker-compose installation is by default installed with Postgres, are you trying to use an external one?

Comment: By default, artifactory docker runs with Derby, and includes the postgresql jar file (but is not used by default). Despite the documentation, seems that DB_TYPE is not enough, but driver must be defined.

Comment: That's half correct - For none Docker installation that's indeed the behavior, but for Docker compose you already have an internal Postgres being used (see step 4)
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerComposeInstallation
Of course, unless you use the manual installation steps, you just need to copy the Artifactory+Postgres compose.yaml file.

Comment: Yes, but this download link with docker compose seems for the pro version, not the oss. And yes, probably they know how to configure it, as I know now. I understand that the docker documentation is for Artifactory 6 and not 7, but this must not prevent to create my custom docker containers. In any case, I have the solution as pointed on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems that I am following a deprecated documentation. Looking into the logs, the variables on the docker must now be:

```
  - JF_SHARED_DATABASE_TYPE=postgresql
  - JF_SHARED_DATABASE_USERNAME=user
  - JF_SHARED_DATABASE_PASSWORD=mypass
  - JF_SHARED_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql-docker:5432/database
```

And searching more, now I have an extra variable:

```
JF_SHARED_DATABASE_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
```

That is the one that solves the problem.

Comment: That’s correct, you should specify the DB driver as well. Some references can be seen here:  https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-docker-examples/blob/master/docker-compose/artifactory/art-compose

Comment: Interesting as on the official documentation I was not able to find any reference to any `DB_DRIVER`.